Run a Python script main.py with a config file from Ansible
I have created several Python scripts, including a main.py script that sequentially runs 4 other Python scripts.
I need to deploy and run them using Ansible. The issue is that I can't use ansible.builtin.script because only main.py is used and not the others, so I'm using ansible.builtin.command.
My problem is that I'm using a config file variables.json, which I first populate with ansible.builtin.template, and then it's sent to the files directory of my role, where the Python scripts are located. But every time, in the return code (rc) of my Python script, I get "undefined variables". I think my scripts can't "see" the config file.
---
- name: Generate the JSON configuration file
  template:
    src: variable.json.j2
    dest: "{{ input_path }}/variable.json"  # Generate the variable.json file in /tmp

- name: Copy all necessary files to the server
  ansible.builtin.copy:
    src: "{{ item }}"
    dest: "{{ input_path }}//{{ item }}"
  loop:
    - main.py
    - migration_zabbix_dezip_config_file.py
    - migration_zabbix_hostname_recovery.py
    - migration_zabbix_create_csv_file.py
  delegate_to: localhost

- name: Run the main.py script 
  ansible.builtin.command:
    cmd: python3 "{{ input_path }}//main.py"


It's hard to tell exactly what's happening without seeing the content of main.py, but it seems likely that the script isn't correctly locating the variable.json file. Make sure that main.py is looking in the right directory for variable.json or pass the file's path explicitly when running the script (e.g., --config {{ input_path }}/variable.json).
